# Can't connect to internet in Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, networking, static-ip

I formatted my computer using windows xp CD. After formatted i try to connect to the     internet using static ip address. The status of the connection is saying "connected" but when i try to use internet it says "can not find server".
I tried it using different browsers like Firefox, opera, and internet explorer but it can't work. the other computers with in the network are working fine.

**Question:** How can i connect my computer to a given network or LAN?

Comment: Can you take a screenshot of your static ip configuration?

Comment: Is this still an issue?

Answer (score 0):

go to **Run**,write **`services.msc`** and then **restart** the **`DNS client`** by right click and restart service
and if you want to get dynamic ip , restart the **`DHCP`** also from the same list of services